# Read Local Json PHPUnit Log File JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, phpunit

I've been trying to parse the phpunit json log using jquery however it returns me error.

I used the following code to parse

```
 <html>
    <head>
     <title>PHPUnit Report</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script src="./jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var json = $.getJSON('logfile.json', function(data){
            alert(data);
        }).success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); });
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

That's the json log file

```
 {"event":"suiteStart","suite":"","tests":22}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","tests":4}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testCriacaoObjeto"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testCriacaoObjeto","status":"pass","time":0.013954162597656,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testAdicionarProduto"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testAdicionarProduto","status":"pass","time":0.015092134475708,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testRemoverProduto"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testRemoverProduto","status":"pass","time":0.0048158168792725,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testLimparCarrinho"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest","test":"Application_Model_CarrinhoTest::testLimparCarrinho","status":"pass","time":0.0047218799591064,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","tests":3}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaCriacaoProduto"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaCriacaoProduto","status":"pass","time":0.0066261291503906,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaErroCriacao"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaErroCriacao","status":"pass","time":0.0081219673156738,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaCadastroProduto"}{"event":"test","suite":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest","test":"Application_Model_ProdutoTest::testaCadastroProduto","status":"pass","time":0.086114883422852,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","tests":4}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"fail","time":0.18276596069336,"trace":[],"message":"Failed asserting node denoted by div#view-content p CONTAINS content \"View script for controller <b>Carrinho<\/b> and script\/action name <b>index<\/b>\""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testAdicionarProdutoAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testAdicionarProdutoAction","status":"pass","time":0.038674831390381,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testRemoverProdutoAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testRemoverProdutoAction","status":"pass","time":0.039582967758179,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testAlterarQuantidadeProdutoAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest","test":"Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testAlterarQuantidadeProdutoAction","status":"pass","time":0.038434982299805,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest","tests":2}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest","test":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest","test":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"fail","time":0.043931007385254,"trace":[],"message":"Failed asserting node denoted by div#view-content p CONTAINS content \"View script for controller <b>Categoria<\/b> and script\/action name <b>index<\/b>\""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest","test":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest::testDetalheAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest","test":"Default_CategoriaControllerTest::testDetalheAction","status":"pass","time":0.040285110473633,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_IndexControllerTest","tests":1}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_IndexControllerTest","test":"Default_IndexControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_IndexControllerTest","test":"Default_IndexControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"fail","time":0.045408964157104,"trace":[],"message":"Failed asserting node denoted by div#welcome h3 CONTAINS content \"This is your project's main page\""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest","tests":2}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"fail","time":0.04747200012207,"trace":[],"message":"Failed asserting last controller used <\"error\"> was \"Produto\""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest::testDetalheAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutoControllerTest::testDetalheAction","status":"fail","time":0.042054891586304,"trace":[],"message":"Failed asserting last controller used <\"error\"> was \"Produto\""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","tests":3}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"pass","time":0.046010971069336,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testBuscarAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testBuscarAction","status":"pass","time":0.043781995773315,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testDetalheAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest","test":"Default_ProdutosControllerTest::testDetalheAction","status":"pass","time":0.04433798789978,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","tests":3}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testIndexAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testIndexAction","status":"pass","time":0.048629999160767,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testLogarAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testLogarAction","status":"pass","time":0.046178817749023,"trace":[],"message":""}{"event":"testStart","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testSairAction"}{"event":"test","suite":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest","test":"Default_UsuarioControllerTest::testSairAction","status":"pass","time":0.04793381690979,"trace":[],"message":""}
```

What's wrong? How could I parse it?

Comment: @nikc Actually It just goes to the error block and show me the alert error. I can't get any real error in the firebug

Comment: Yes you can, try harder. You're not using any of the params that are being passed in to the error handler (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/). And you can check if it's a network error. Nobody can debug without information. Yopu can step through the code in Firebug and add watches.

Comment: @nikc I've got "parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"

Comment: Well there you have it. You JSON is garbled during the transfer. Watch the network transfers in Firebug, you can see there how/if the data is being amended to. You can also change `getJSON` to just `get` and `console.log` the data you're getting in. (`getJSON` always implies automatic parsing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your JSON is as it should be, phpunit outputs the JSON as an event occurs...each of these events can easily be parsed but doing them all as one will throw errors.

I too would prefer to have a format that can be parsed straight away in JS or using php's json_decode but looks like it won't happen for now...

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's missing is the comma between the events and the wrapping square brackets. You can add them manually and then json_decode.

```
$json = file_get_contents('/log.json');
$json = '['.str_replace('}{', '},{', $json).']';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert json file to valid one using `sed` beforehand:

```
    sed -i.bak 's/^{$/[{/g;s/^}$/}]/g;s/}{/},{/g' logfile.json
```